# Strip Some ASCII Codes from FIle Efficiently?

Tags: stream, char, ascii, filestream, memory-mapped-files

I have an on-disk file of 100mb (can be up to 300mb). There are nulls and some other control characters that should not be in there. At first I read the string into memory and then re-read it Char by Char and then removed the offending Chars and put the clean stuff into a StringBuilder and then did a ToString on that.

That uses too much memory of course. I need to figure out how to strip out bad ASCII values on disk. Maybe (.NET 4) Memory Mapped File Stream is the right thing (I checked this out from [Memory Mapped File to Read End of File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402725/memory-mapped-file-to-read-end-of-file) a while ago)?

All ideas appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to remove and re-order the file or can you replace the bad chars with spaces to keep the same length?

Comment: I can replace bad chars with String.Empty because they are mostly Null and Tab characters.

Comment: Why aren't you just directly writing to the output file? There's no reason to store the entire output in memory at once.

Comment: I am not writing to the file directly because I don't know how to do that. Open a StreamReader and a StreamWriter on the same file at the same time? Maybe I'm overthinking this but I am confused

Answer (score 0):

If you need to shrink the file to remove bad characters then simply read the file in a character or block at a time and write it out to a new file skipping bad characters.
This also gives you an undo!

If you can replace bad characters in place so that the length of the file doesn't change then map the file and scan over the memory replacing each bad character with eg space (ascii 32). This is simplest and probably faster - but either way you are going to be dominated by the raw disk i/o

Comment: Do you have a sample (pseudo or real code) on how to make this happen?